# AngularJS animations with ng-class when swapping between two classes

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions, angularjs-animation

Using AngularJS and ng-class, I'm trying to animate when classes change between three possible states. I have a div that can be in three states, represented by classes on the div. The states are defined as follows:

1. `<div class='myDiv'></div>`
2. `<div class='myDiv foo'></div>`
3. `<div class='myDiv bar'></div>`

Note that the classes `foo` and `bar` are exclusive meaning `<div class="myDiv foo bar"></div>` is not possible. I'm using the ng-class directive as follows:

`<div class="myDiv" ng-class="{foo: first, bar: second}"></div>`

The controller ensures that the boolean values first and second can both be simultaneously false but not true.

I'm finding that ngAnimate correctly detects css transitions between states 1<-->2 and 1<-->3 but does not from 2<-->3. I've tried adding css transition code for class selectors such as `.myDiv.foo`, `.myDiv.bar`, `.myDiv.foo-add-active`, etc. but either ngAnimate doesn't detect them (meaning it doesn't add the -add and -add-active classes) or the animation classes are added but no transition occurs.

Here is a link to a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k032s608/1/) demonstrating the problem. Clicking either button and then re-clicking it shows the working transitions. Clicking either button and then clicking the other button shows the lack of transitions.

Is there a magic set of transitions that ngAnimate will pick up properly? Or is this a case where I need to not use ng-class and write my own custom directive?

Answer (score 1):

If you watch the `style` property of `.myDiv` in the console, you'll see that (for whatever reason) ngAnimate is setting `transition-property` to `none`.

Not sure why that is, but the fix it to slap `!important` on the `transition` within your CSS:

```
.myDiv{
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear !important;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear !important;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear !important;
    transition: all 1s linear !important;
}
```

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gd1hz5b7/

Comment: This definitely works and is necessary for angular 1.2.x. As it turns out, this behavior is fixed in 1.3.0 so I'm adding an answer with that information for better visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Odd timing but AngularJS 1.3.0 was just released and this now works as expected. couzzi's answer is correct for version 1.2.x, which I'm sure many people will stick with until 1.3.0 see more real life use.

Change the external resources to be:

`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js`
`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular-animate.min.js`

and the original posted fiddle (without !important) works fine. I've created a new [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c56n9gwa/) for completeness.